# Reference Data for Programming Language Structures

Tags: programming-languages, multilingual

I wish to ask about the existence of resources listing the mapping between programming language structures and their presence in various programming languages. So something like the following table

| Language | HAS_ASYNC | IS_STRONGLY_TYPED | HAS_GENERICS | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Python | YES | NO | YES | .... |
| Java | NO | YES | YES | .... |
| Kotlin | YES | YES | YES | .... |
| .... | .... | .... | .... | .... |

If not, even a grand list of such structures without mappings would be helpful starting point for me i.e. **HAS_ASYNC**, **IS_STRONGLY_TYPED**, **HAS_GENERICS**, etc.

I have been able to find [this](https://cse.sc.edu/%7Emgv/csce330f13/index.html) (somewhat old) course that details some of the possible structures but not much else.